# How do I insert an umlaut on the u in ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, 13.04, language-support, input-language, special-characters

I have already activated the compose key (left <kbd>CTRL</kbd>).  According to all the forums I've read, I have to punch in <kbd>Compose</kbd>, followed by <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>.  This is what I get as a result:  ´u'

I am really stuck here.  Any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: Which keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: Also look here for some solutions including Linux: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/724/wie-schreibt-man-umlaute-und-scharfes-s-auf-nichtdeutschen-tastaturen

Comment: I found it out in the end :)

Comment: Or just copy-paste your ü from this thread ;-)

Comment: Try this: Übüntü

Comment: Adrian May is correct. These various steps are a bit ridiculous, and continue to change. Just Google "<character> umlaut" and copy/paste.  If you want it to be fast-access, keep a text file handy with all the various characters you use.

Answer (score 66):

## UPDATED

I have worked it out.

Firstly, set your Compose Key to Right Alt (<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> on my keyboard) so that it doesn't interfere with the short cuts for copy, paste and many other combinations.

then go to your document and

- press the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> button
- release it
- then type in <kbd>u</kbd>
- followed by <kbd>"</kbd>
- which gives you a **ü**

Hope this helps

Comment: To find out how to set the Compose Key, head over to the [Ubuntu Documentation page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey)

Comment: For those looking here, at the moment it is Compose then " then u.  For this laptop compose is `Shift` and `AltGr` pressed down together so the actual key sequence is: `Shift+AltGr` then `"u`  For my other machines it is just `AltGr` then `"u`

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to set the Compose Key to Right Alt, as this key (Alt Graph) is already set up for shortcuts (see my gist [Typography symbols for Linux using AltGr & Compose keys](https://gist.github.com/growdigital/ae387a2eef0ce7bc2007c41705e161e6)) Better to use the right Windows key.

Answer (score 18):

**Update** For OS: Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64

Alternate characters (like umlauts) are inserted using multiple keystrokes in conjunction with the [compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key#Common_compose_combinations). In ubuntu 16.04, compose key binding is turned off by default which can be enabled from

```
System settings-> Keyboard-> Shortcuts tab-> Typing column-> Compose Key
```

[image: Screenshot]

If the value in front of compose key is *Disabled*, click the value and Press the key to bind from the keyboard. In my case, compose key is set to **AltGr key**. Now you system to ready to print all german umlauts as below

<kbd>compose key</kbd> + <kbd>"</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>  = Ä

<kbd>compose key</kbd> + <kbd>"</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>  = Ö

<kbd>compose key</kbd> + <kbd>"</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>  = Ü

<kbd>compose key</kbd> + <kbd>"</kbd> + <kbd>ss</kbd> = ß

<kbd>compose key</kbd> + <kbd>ss</kbd> = ß

Bam you go!

Comment: for me, it is only `compose key + ss` to type ß

Comment: For upper-case ß, use `compose key` + `SS` = ẞ

Answer (score 13):

I know this question specifies 13.04 but thought I would add a solution for 18.04.

I found the default on my machine without making any changes in preferences was the following (I am using a UK keyboard):

<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> followed by the character to add the umlaut to (i.e <kbd>u</kbd>)

Comment: the easiest for me so far!

Comment: This answer should be more highly rated! The compose-key stuff is a bit of a hack in my opinion and it's better to use what's built into the keyboard layout (although sadly, it's not very well documented).
It's also worth noting that this particular solution is not limited to any specific distro or version - it will work on any Linux distrubution that is using a keyboard layout with an alt-gr key (i.e. any of the European ones).

Comment: by far the simplest solution, excellent!

Comment: I love you so much - this works on Manjaro too.  Previously I could only get a capital I with an umlaut by pressing and holding Shift _then_ AltGr, then pressing I, releasing AltGr, and pressing 2.  Your method works so much more easily and for lowercase.

Answer (score 8):

I did it using Ubuntu 15.10 with a UK keyboard and EN-GB keyboard. I don't know what a Compose key is so didn't intentionally use one. Instead the following keystrokes put umlauts over ü and ö.

- press the <kbd>Shift+AltGr</kbd> buttons
- release them
- then type in <kbd>u</kbd> or <kbd>o</kbd>
- followed by <kbd>"</kbd>
- which gives you a **ü** or **ö**.

Cheers

Comment: Confirm works in uBuntu 18.04 LTS. Exact sequence is (1) `Shift` + `AltGr` (these can now be released), (2) `Shift` + `2` (for quotation marks and now `Shift` can be released), (3) whatever letter you want an umlaut on eg. `u`.

Answer (score 6):

In Ubuntu 18.10 and newer the best option if you regularly need umlauts is to use `gnome-tweaks` to activate the compose key -- install with: `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`

Activate the [compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey): Start `Tweaks` and choose at `Keyboard & Mouse -> Compose-Key` to designate your compose key.   <kbd>AltGr</kbd> or Right-Alt is standard.

Now you can type Umlaut as explained in [other answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/304286/840187): <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd> then <kbd>u</kbd> will get you `ü` -- in general you can add any umlaut to letters that take an umlaut or [diaeresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_%28diacritic%29) with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd> followed by the letter.

Comment: To install Tweaks: `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`.The default `Compose` key in uBuntu 18.04 was `Scroll Lock`.

Answer (score 3):

First go in **System settings** > **Personal** > **Keyboard Layout** and add German layout:

[image]

Now, select **German** layaut and check **Layout Chart** to see where is 'u with umlaut':

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Afrikaans this also works for "deelteken e" and "kappie e" on Linux:

- after having setup the compose key
- press the AltGr button
- release
- then type in e
- followed by ^ (shift + 6) or "
- which gives you ê or ë

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> followed by the unicode characters, pointed out [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1043016/511544):

> And the other is typing the Unicode character's code point. To do
>   this, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, release all keys (you'll see an underlined
>   u), type the code point desired, and then press <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to
>   complete.
>
> For example, a common one I use is referred to as “Smart Quotes” which
>   are U+201C & U+201D respectively. So you would type 201C or 201D after
>   releasing the initial keys, and complete the process with Space or
>   Enter.

It works on Ubuntu 18.04, but I am not sure about older version.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this easy solution **without any hacks or system file editing**. It only uses Gnome builtin tools.

1. Open GNOME Tweak Tool and enable: *Keyboard & Mouse* → *Show Extended Input Sources*
2. Restart your Gnome session
3. Open GNOME Settings and go to *Keyboard* → *Input Sources* and add the new Keyboard Layout *German (US)*.

The layout is a simple US Keyboard with Ä | Ü | Ö mapped to <kbd>Alt GR</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> | <kbd>U</kbd> | <kbd>O</kbd> and ß to <kbd>Alt GR</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Comment: It looks like you're linking to your own blog post here - if so please do mention in the post that it's yours - we have rather strict rules about "disclosing affiliation" for links (see [this harshly worded page in the Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help/promotion))

Comment: @Zanna It's not a first offense.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I was not aware of that, sorry! I got an answer ban now, and I only have two answers left that I could improve. I'd like to contribute to another question, but I can't. I've removed my blog link, so would you please mind removing your downvote? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe my one is the easiest procedure to follow. It worked for me for any version of Ubuntu. The steps are as follows:

1. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> simultaneously.
2. Release <kbd>U</kbd> and press `00` (zero twice)
3. Press <kbd>F</kbd> & <kbd>C</kbd> for printing **ü**.
   Or press <kbd>D</kbd> & <kbd>C</kbd> for printing **Ü**.

I wish you good luck!