# How to set a Compose Key in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, compose-key

Now that Unity is gone, the usual way of setting a Compose Key (via Keyboard Preferences > Layout) no longer works (because in Ubuntu 18.04, Devices > Keyboard has no Layout tab).

How do we set a Compose Key in Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You may use *(GNOME) Tweaks* to set the option.

First install Tweaks by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

(or `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool`).

Alternatively, for those who prefer the GUI:

1. launch the Ubuntu Software application.
2. search for "gnome tweaks".
3. install.

Then launch Tweaks and go to "*Keyboard & Mouse*" section. The "Compose Key" options is disabled by default. Click on the "*Disabled*" button.

[image]

Then a window will pop up. Toggle the switch at the top on and then you'll be select the compose key

[image]

Comment: I don't have Scroll Lock, so I tried PrtScn, RightAlt, and none of them worked, what I'm missing?

Comment: Same here, I set it to Right Alt and it doesn't work.

Comment: @zwolin Did you check out [the question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072305/enabling-compose-key-with-tweaks-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-18-04) posted by Michael?

Comment: @pomsky thank you, now I did. But it didn't help my case. I solved it just now by setting in GNOME Tweaks: Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options ->Key to choose the 3rd level -> Right Alt. And now my Polish diacritic characters work as expected

Comment: Maybe I should ask this as a separate question but is it possible to somehow set multiple compose keys (left and right alt)? It does not seem possible using the Tweaks menu.

Comment: @Kvothe Sorry, no idea :( Might be possible using `dconf`/`gsettings`. Asking a new question sounds like a good idea.

Comment: @Kvothe It is possible, see my answer.

Answer (score 13):

To expand upon what @pomsky detailed in their answer, the [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html) covers the two solutions available.

One is through installing Gnome Tweak Tool via the terminal like so: `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool`

And the other is typing the Unicode character's code point. To do this, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, release all keys (you'll see an underlined `u`), type the code point desired, and then press <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to complete.

For example, a common one I use is referred to as “Smart Quotes” which are U+201C & U+201D respectively. So you would type 201C or 201D after releasing the initial keys, and complete the process with <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 5):

Issue `man xkeyboard-config` and look for the compose options (shortcut: enter `/compose:`).
You will find

```
compose:ralt          Right Alt                  
compose:lwin          Left Win                   
compose:lwin-altgr    3rd level of Left Win      
compose:rwin          Right Win                  
compose:rwin-altgr    3rd level of Right Win     
compose:menu          Menu                       
compose:menu-altgr    3rd level of Menu          
compose:lctrl         Left Ctrl                  
compose:lctrl-altgr   3rd level of Left Ctrl     
compose:rctrl         Right Ctrl                 
compose:rctrl-altgr   3rd level of Right Ctrl    
compose:caps          Caps Lock                  
compose:caps-altgr    3rd level of Caps Lock     
compose:102           <Less/Greater>             
compose:102-altgr     3rd level of <Less/Greater>
compose:paus          Pause                      
compose:prsc          PrtSc                      
compose:sclk          Scroll Lock
```

Let us say you want to pick <kbd>Pause</kbd> as the compose key.
Just issue

```
setxkbmap -option compose:paus
```

To make it reboot-persistent, open `/etc/default/keyboard` with your favorite editor.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard
```

and to the line `XKBOPTIONS` add `compose:paus`. If you had other options already,
separate them with commas. For example:

```
XKBOPTIONS="terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,compose:paus"
```

Multiple compose keys can be used simultaneously.

Comment: Always nice to have a pure CLI alternative  Thanks!

Comment: @Tim You are welcome! This has an advantage of not requiring Gnome or Ubuntu or anything of the sort, only X11.

Comment: setxkbmap -option compose:paus work for me

but changing 

XKBOPTIONS="terminate:ctrl_alt_bks,compose:paus"


In /etc/default/keyboard
dont work for me :/ I don't understand.

Answer (score 4):

The dconf setting that worked for my GNOME 3.28.2 is

```
/org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options
```

To set the Scroll Lock as the compose key, the value should be

```
['compose:sclk']
```

See [the gnome-tweaks source code](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-tweaks/blob/b7c84b1037450f6ecab4aaaaa8d4e6b6c8d73554/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_keymouse.py#L44) for other potential values.

That means you can run a command like this:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['compose:sclk']"
```

Comment: In case you would like to define multiple compose keys, simply extend the array: `['compose:prsc', 'compose:rwin']`. Another way to show the list of possible keys: `grep "compose:" /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst`

Comment: Eg `dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['compose:sclk']"`