# Enabling Compose key with Tweaks doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, compose-key

I have a new installation of Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot with Windows 8.1, with (GNOME) Tweaks installed, I need compose key to type Brazilian accent words (à á ã ç), so I installed Tweaks, "US intl with dead key" keyboard layout and followed the instructions on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028957/how-to-set-a-compose-key-in-ubuntu-18-04). I don't have <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>, so I tried with <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> & right-<kbd>Alt</kbd>, none of them worked.

This is the key sequence, compose key (<kbd>PrtScn</kbd> or right-<kbd>Alt</kbd>) + <kbd>'</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>, did not work, changed the sequence to compose key (<kbd>PrtScn</kbd> or right-<kbd>Alt</kbd>) + <kbd>c</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> both gave me c.

Am I missing some steps?

Comment: What happens if you simply press <right-alt>+<,> (comma) and <right-alt>+<shift>+<,>?

Comment: Compose Key disabled, <right-alt>+<,> (comma) = ç, and <right-alt>+<shift>+<,> = Ç, with Compose Key enabled to Right Alt, <right-alt>+<,> (comma) =  (blank), and <right-alt>+<shift>+<,> = <

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the "**US international with dead keys**" layout if you're using the compose key. Simply use the standard US layout.

---

With the "**US international with dead keys**" layout, you can get some of those special characters without enabling the compose key simply by using the "level 3 select key" (level 3 select key is usually <kbd>AltGr</kbd> aka right-<kbd>Alt</kbd> key). See the layout:

[image]

For example,

- <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (comma) gives "**ç**" and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> gives "**Ç**"
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> gives "**á**" and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> gives "**Á**"

Comment: great, thanks so much for your detailed explanation.