# Shortcut to insert bullet point • into text in Linux (Ubuntu 18.04LTS)

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I am new to Linux and I would like to insert the character that corresponds to the bullet point • when typing text.

I know that I can to do by typing (<kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> and then 2022) but that is quite a tedious solution and I am looking for a easier way to do so (on my macbook, running OSX, it is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> for instance).

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: I want to insert the character itself in a any text editor, from nano to vi, and also in the Terminal. I already know how to do this using the menu button on Office ;) Thanks!

Comment: Edit this question, copy bullet point and then paste it wherever you want :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way is to [define a compose key](https://askubuntu.com/q/1028957). Then you can do:

<kbd>Compose</kbd> followed by <kbd>.</kbd> followed by <kbd>=</kbd> => •

This page lists characters you can type in Gtk using a compose key:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GtkComposeTable

Comment: Oh this is exactly what I was looking for. I already set the Compose key, but I could not find the shortcut . followed by = which gives •

Comment: Do you know where I can find the other shortcuts like this one? I have been looking for this for a while... And is it possible to change/edit/add these?

Comment: @LeChat: I edited my answer and added a link.

Comment: IThis is really confusing to get working by reading.  I need to see it happen to get it.  Can someone post a link to an instructional video somewhere?  I've enabled the compose key and tried several times to get any extra characters to show up but I must be doing something wrong or skipping a step and really need to see it in action to be able to confirm which step I'm skipping, if that makes sense.c

Comment: @JoshuaRobison: I would suggest that you submit a new question where you ask for clarifications about the use of a compose key. If you do, please refer to [the question I linked to](https://askubuntu.com/q/1028957).

Answer (score 5):

Type `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`U` followed by 2022.
As you type you will see a `u` followed by the digits, underlined, where you're typing. Then hit `Enter`. The underlined expression should become a bullet point.

[Full list of Unicode characters](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GtkComposeTable) don't ask me why, the value 2022 isn't there for the typographical bullet but it works

EDIT: see comments below to understand why I'm leaving this non-answer here.

Comment: This question is specifically seeking an alternative to this solution.  `compose`+`.`, then `=` is that alternative.

Comment: I came to this page via a Google search. As is often the case, I read the question title, confirmed it was what I was looking for without bothering the read the content. When I scrolled down to the only answer, it did not meet my needs. (Ubuntu Mate 20.04 LTS) When I found a solution, I came back here and posted it. 
You are 100% right, my answer doesn't address the OP's needs. But, given that others will do what I did (one person has up-voted so far), and I've linked other unicodes, I'm going to leave it here.

Comment: Fair enough.  You may wish to edit the answer to specifically mention that that's why you're presenting this answer... and/or also include the other answer.  Such an update would likely get it another upvote from me.