# Shortcut (Ctrl+Shift+8) to insert bullet point • into text in Linux no longer works (Ubuntu 19.10)

Tags: shortcut-keys, 19.10

The accepted answer to [Shorcut to insert bullet point • into text in Linux (Ubuntu 18.04LTS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077798/shorcut-to-insert-bullet-point-into-text-in-linux-ubuntu-18-04lts) is not the answer that I was looking for.  For me I want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> as I always have done for years for inserting a bullet point.  Any chance that anyone knows how to reimplement this without the compose key option?